# Using IF criteria on partial sheet name

Tags: arrays, excel, typescript, performance, office-scripts

I need the script to go through each tab in the workbook and hide three columns if the tab starts with "TRI". My code works, but it is extremely slow. I'm looking for ways to make it faster. Please provide examples of the needed code as I don't think I understand the correct syntax to do it with an array or by declaring tName/checkTRI outside of the loop as the code always breaks when I try to do either of those.

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
 
    let ws = workbook.getWorksheets();

    for (let w of ws) {
        let tName = w.getName();
        let checkTRI = tName.substring(0, 3);

       if(checkTRI=="TRI"){
           w.getRange("F:F").setColumnHidden(true);
           w.getRange("G:G").setColumnHidden(true);
           w.getRange("H:H").setColumnHidden(true);
       }
    }
}
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 0):

- Hidden three columns all at once

```
function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {
    let ws = workbook.getWorksheets();
    const key = "TRI"
    for (let w of ws) {
        let tName = w.getName();
        let checkTRI = tName.substring(0, 3).toUpperCase();
        w.getRange("F:H").setColumnHidden(checkTRI === key);
    }
    console.log("DONE")
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but it does not hide the columns. Also, can you tell me what adding toUpperCase does for this?

Comment: `toUpperCase` convert a string to upper case. `I tried this but it does not hide the columns.` What's the sheet name? Please share a screenshot in your post.

Comment: I have tested code w/o any issures. `How To` is the only visible sheet after running code. You can try to remove `.toUpperCase()`, it doesn't change anything in your case.